# Custom sharding or auto Sharding on SolrCloud?

Tags: solr, routes, sharding, solrcloud

I want to establish a SolrCloud clsuter for over 10 millions of news articles. After reading this article: [Shards and Indexing Data in SolrCloud](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Shards+and+Indexing+Data+in+SolrCloud), I have a plan as follows:

1. Add prefix ED2001! to document ID where ED means some newspaper source and 2001 is the year part in published date of news article, i.e. I want to put all news articles of specific news paper source published in specific year to a shard.
2. Create collection with router.name set to compositeID.
3. Add documents?
4. Query Collection?

Practically, I got some questions:

1. How to add doucments based on this plan? Do I have to specify special parameters when updating the collection/core?
2. Is this called "custom sharding"? If not, what is "custom sharding"?
3. Is auto sharding a better choice for my case since there's a shard-splitting feature for auto sharding when the shard is too big?
4. Can I query without _router_ parameter?

EDIT @ 2015/9/2:

5. This is how I think SolrCloud will do: "The amount of news articles of specific newspaper source of specific year tends to be around a fix number, e.g. Every year ED has around 80,000 articles, so each shard's size won't increase dramatically. For the next year's news articles of ED, I only have to add prefix 'ED2016!' to document ID, SolrCloud will create a new shard for me (which contains all ED2016 articles), and later the Leader will spread the replica of this new shard to other nodes (per replica per node other than leader?)". Am I right? If yes, it seems no need for shard-splitting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Answer-1:** If have the schema (structure) of the document then you can provide the same in `schema.xml` configuration or you can use Solr's `schema-less` mode for indexing the document. The `schema-less` mode will automatically identify the fields in your document and index them. The configuration of `schema-less` mode is little different then schema based configuration mode in solr. Afterwards, you need to send the documents to solr for indexing using curl or solrj java api. Essentially, solr provides rest end points for all the different operations. You can write the client in any language which suits you better.

**Answer-2:** What you have mentioned in your plan, use of `compositeId`, is called **custom sharding**. Because you are deciding to which shard a particular document should go.

**Answer-3:** I would suggest to go with auto-sharding feature if are not certain how much data you need to index at present and in future. As the index size increases you can split the shards and scale the solr horizontally.

**Answer-4:** I went through the solr documentation, did not find anywhere mentioning `_route_` as mandatory parameter. But in some situations, this may improve query performance because it overcomes network latency when querying all the shards.

**Answer-5:** The meaning of auto-sharding is routing the document to a shards, based on the hash range assigned while creating the shards. It does not create the new shards automatically, just by specifying a new prefix for `compositeId`. So once the index grows large enough in size, you might need to split it. Check here for [more](https://lucidworks.com/blog/shard-splitting-in-solrcloud/).

Comment: If you are using solr's `collection api` for creating the shards and not using the default document routing mechanism, then in future you can add/remove shards in your collection. The approach you have described in your question is correct and seems to fit your requirement.

Comment: \@abhishek: I use the compositeID for 2 purposes: First, controlling the shard size since each year each source's no. of articles is always around a stable amount (I edit my question based on this thought). In practical application, users constantly query articles based on year range, thus I can apply \_route_ with specific year list, just like what you have mentioned in your answer.

Comment: Your thinking and approach is correct and looks practical to me. Here is the link to [Collection API](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Collections+API).

Comment: I would suggest you, start a solr server in cloud mode and create shard using `collection api` and use `compositeID` for routing the document. Initially start with two shards, index some `(n,m)` documents in each shards and then add a new shard in the same collection using `collection api`. Basically you don't specify number of shard at the time of starting the solr. That will solve your purpose.

Comment: I need to modify my approach since compositeID needs to specify numShards first and there's no way I know how many years of docs I'll put in. My thought in question 5 seems wrong! Maybe I have to use implicit router from very beginning.

Comment: **If you use the "compositeId" router, you can send documents with a prefix in the document ID which will be used to calculate the hash Solr uses to determine the shard a document is sent to for indexing.** This is from Solr Documentation. I not getting one thing, where it say, if you use `compositeId` then you have to use numShards option.

Comment: Check the topic "Collections API" under 'SolrCloud configuration and Parameters" section in reference guide. In the description of 'numShards' query parameter of CREATE action, it said "The number of shards to be created as part of the collection. __This is a required parameter when using the 'compositeId' router__."

Answer (score 3):

This is actually a guide to answer my own question:

I kinda understand some concepts:

1. "custom sharding" **IS NOT** "custom hashing".
2. Solr averagely splits hash values as default hashing behavior.
3. compositeId router applies "custom hashing" cause it changes default hashing behavior  by prefixing shard_key/num-of-bits.
4. Implicit router applies "custom sharding" since we need to manually specify which shards our docs will be sent to.
5. compositeId router still is auto sharding since it's Solr who see the shard_key prefix and route the docs to specific shards.
6. compositeId router needs to specify numShards parameter (possbily because Solr needs to distribute various hash value space ranges for each of the shard).

So obviously my strategy doesn't work since I need to always add in new year's news articles to Solr and there's no way I can predict how many shards in advance. So to speak, Implicit router seems a possible choice for me (We create shard we need and add docs to shard we intend to).

Comment: For point 5, Shawn Heisey has good comment to my question on online doc of Aapche Solr Reference Guide: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Shards+and+Indexing+Data+in+SolrCloud?focusedCommentId=61317676#comment-61317676

Comment: So for time-series data, custom sharding is a better strategy since we diecide what timelines of data distributed to which shards.

Comment: is it possible to route documents to a specific shard? e.g if collection has two shards, shard_1 and shard_2, what is the easiest way to route to shard_1?